# How i can implement media player media session for lock screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, background-music, android-mediasession

I'm building a music app and i need to display control panel of my media player on lock screen. How i can do that? I'm already read about media session but idk how to correctly implement it. I need some example